# Remove from first dash and beyond

Tags: regex, coldfusion

How would I strip everything beyond the first "-pg" using coldfusion regex replace?

http://www.abc.com/Webpage-pg3.html

So in this case the end result would be

http://www.abc.com/Webpage

Comment: The description does not quite match the end result. What is the ultimate goal, remove a suffix "-pg{n}.html" from a series of url strings?

Comment: How I read that question is: Start matching characters from the beginning of the string, up to the first occurrence of "-pg", and then remove "-pg"...along with *everything else that follows*.

Comment: @Shawn - Probably. But my thinking was - eliciting more information about the goal would help others suggest the most appropriate expression. Assuming a regex is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about coldfusion but this regex would match -pg and everything after and store it in the first capturing group:

```
(-pg.*)
```

If you then replace it with an empty string you'd get the desired result. You can see it in action here: http://regexr.com?2v965

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're locking yourself into a regex solution. This should work fine:

```
<cfset stringToCheck = "http://www.abc.com/Webpage-pg3.html">
<cfset stringToFind = "-pg">

<cfset newString = left(stringToCheck,find(stringToFind,stringToCheck)-1)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<cfscript>
newString = urlString.replaceAll( "-pg.*", "" );
</cfscript>
```

Syntax:

`String.replaceAll( regex, replacement )`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Or you could skip regex, and use the java String methods, like this one liner for CF9:

```
<cfscript>
newString = ! urlString.contains( "-pg" ) ? "" : urlString.substring( 0, urlString.indexOf( "-pg" ) );
</cfscript>
```

The same, without the ternary operator, for older versions of CF:

```
<cfscript>
if ( urlString.contains( "-pg" ) ) {
    newString = urlString.substring( 0, urlString.indexOf( "-pg" ) );
}
else {
    newString = "";
}
</cfscript>
```

Ran some benchmarks, it seems the `String.replaceAll()` method is the fastest on my machine.

```
<cfscript>
old = "http://www.abc.com/Webpage-pg3.html";

// benchmarks
sys = createObject( "java", "java.lang.System" );

// 35072 ns
// 28160 ns
t1 = sys.nanoTime();
    new1 = old.replaceAll( "-pg.*", "" );
t1 = sys.nanoTime() - t1;

// 20992 ns
// 18176 ns
t2 = sys.nanoTime();
    new2 = old.contains( "-pg" ) ? "" : old.substring( 0, old.indexOf( "-pg" ) );
t2 = sys.nanoTime() - t2;
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
REReplace("http://www.abc.com/Webpage-pg3.html","(.+)-pg.*","\1")
```

**Pedantic edit:**

```
REReplace("http://www.abc.com/Webpage-pg3.html","(.+?)-pg.*","\1")
```

Comment: @ShawnHolmes The pattern works with the example of the OP. A simple ? after the + quantifier will "solve" "your" "problem".

Comment: It worked on his example, but technically did not answer the question until you amended it. As is very often the case, when questions are asked, the asker themselve does not understand the depth of the question (in this case, assuming there would never be a 2nd occurrence of -pg, which could potentially happen later on in the string).

Answer (score 0):

I was going to propose what Jason already proposed

```
<cfset part = listFirst(urlString, '-') />
```

If there is a simple option take it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<cfset string = "http://www.abc.com/Webpage-pg3.html"  />

<cfset new = ReReplace(string,'(.+?)-pg.*','\1','ONE') />

<cfoutput>#new#</cfoutput>
```

In this solution, I used a non-greedy match up to the first occurrence of -pg.